# WCF WSDL Page Missing

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I have been following along with the Aaron Skonnard videos on creating a WCF service.  I have completed the tutorial found [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Building-RESTful-Services-with-WCF-Part-2) and when finished the WSDL page that would normally be available to a consumer of this service is not found (page states that "Endpoint is not found").

I have found many references to this issue including adding a 'mex' endpoint, adding httpGetEnabled, etc. but nothing seems to work.  I believe this is because the tutorial removes the service files from the website code behind and instead uses a reference to another project.

I like the way the service is created with this tutorial but need to know how to get this WSDL page to display properly so others can consume my service.  Is this no longer the correct way to create services in .NET 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think REST based services (WebAPI) create a WSDL at all. I beleive the WSDL is only for the SOAP based WCF services.